# Does List<String>.Contains(mystring) do a reference comparison or a value comparison?

Tags: c#, string

Does List.Contains(mystring) do a reference comparison or a value comparison?
Eg I have this code:

```
/// <summary>
/// If the value isn't null or an empty string, 
/// and doesn't exist in the list, it adds it to the list
/// </summary>
static void AddToListIfNotEmpty(List<string> thelist, SqlString val)
{
  string value = val.ToString().Trim();
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
  {
    bool found = false;
    foreach (string x in thelist) if (x == value) found = true;
    if (!found) thelist.Add(value);
  }
}
```

Can i simplify the foreach and following line to:

```
if (!thelist.Contains(value)) thelist.Add(value);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IList<T>` uses `Comparator<T>.Default` to do the comparisons, and in turn that compares by value for `String` objects.

If you wanted to, you could move your items to an `IDictionary<T, bool>` or something similar, where you can specify your `IComparator` - specifying one that checks for reference. (even though in that case, you're better off with the foreach loop)

If you can use LINQ, you could create a statement there with a reference comparison, too.

Comment: Comparing by reference makes no sense. There is no way a `SqlString` reference will be equal to that of a `string` already in the list?

Comment: You're correct, I didn't notice that. That might make the Equals method return false, too.

In that case, using the IDictionary trick or LINQ is his option,

Comment: Wait, I was confused a bit. He's comparing the ToString().Trim() value, not the SqlString itself. The Equals might work, and even the reference comparison if the strings are interned.

Comment: Strings are not interned automatically, but the `String` class' equality operator compares by value, not by reference. To compare references, you'd have to cast it to `object` first.

Comment: Casting will obviously not help. That's why I suggested LINQ or `IDictionary`.

Comment: I think i've confused things by having my sqlstring in there. You can assume that everything is strings in my example.

Comment: I know. Still, my answer stands. :)

Answer (score 5):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) of `List<T>.Contains`

> This method determines equality using
>   the default equality comparer
>   `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` for T,
>   the type of values in the list.
>
> ...
>   The  Default property checks
>   whether type T implements the
>   `IEquatable<T>`  generic interface and
>   if so returns an `EqualityComparer<T>`
>   that uses that implementation.
>   Otherwise it returns an
>   `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses the
>   overrides of `Object.Equals` and
>   `Object.GetHashCode`  provided by `T`.

Looking at reflector (and by the principle of least surprise), String Equality has value type semantics - so they are equal if they have the same strings. Both `Equals(Object)` and `IEquatable.Equals(T)` delegate to `String::EqualsHelper`

Answer (score 4):

Comparing for all strings is overloaded to be by value. Sorry didn't notice you had a SqlString, why not use it's ToString() method and add that? Your shortened method won't compile.

Comment: What do you mean it won't compile? It will compile just fine. `value` is `val` converted to a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can simplify (in terms of code, not [complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory)*) by removing the foreach, but your simplification is not functionally identical to your original.

The simplied, functional equivalent would be:

```
static void AddToListIfNotEmpty(List<string> thelist, SqlString val)
{
    string value = val.ToString().Trim();
    if (value != string.Empty && !thelist.Contains(value))
        thelist.Add(value);
}
```

Note that your `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` will never encounter a `null` reference for the string. *Edit*: after checking, I noticed that the `SqlString.ToString()` method converts a NULL SqlString to a literal value "Null", which is not what you want, I imagine. You should add this as the first thing to do in your method:

```
if (val.IsNull)
    return;
```

Lastly, returning to my complexity comment: if you're dealing with a large amount of elements, you might want to look at [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead of using a `List` (same namespace). It won't maintain the order in which strings are added, but it's `Contains` operation is [O(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), while your current one is [O(n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).