# How distinguish between objects type c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model

I am creating a basketball WPF app which displays a `HomeTeam` and an `AwayTeam`.
 I have created a `Player` object and in the main window I have created `ObservableCollection` of player objects for both the home (`HomePlayersList`) and the away teams (`AwayPlayersList`). I have used `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the player object so when `IsInGame` bool is true the player gets added to one of the two `ObservableCollection<Player>` depending on the count. (If list one `ObservableCollection<Player> HomeTeam` or `ObservableCollection<Player> AwayTeam` count is 5, then the rest gets added to the substitution list `ObservableCollection<Team> HomeSub` or `ObservableCollection<Team> AwaySub`.)

But I am trying to distinguish whether the player is in the home or away team, and depending on which list the player is in, the player would be added to the new list of home or away.

```
public static ObservableCollection<Player> HomePlayersList;
public static ObservableCollection<Player> AwayPlayersList;
public static ObservableCollection<Player> HomeTeam = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
public static ObservableCollection<Player> AwayTeam = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
public static ObservableCollection<Player> HomeSub = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
public static ObservableCollection<Player> AwaySub = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
public static int HomeSubCount = 7;

public class Player: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static bool IsHome = true;
    private static int TotalSelected = 1;
    public string Id { get; set; }           //player ID
    public string FirstName { get; set; }    //player first name
    public string SecondName { get; set; }    //player second name
    public string KnownName { get; set; }     //player known name
    public string Position { get; set; }      //player position
    public string Number { get; set; }       //player number

    public bool isInGame;

    public bool IsInGame
    {
        get { return isInGame; }

        set
        {
            if (value != isInGame)
            {
                isInGame = value;

                if (isInGame)
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsInGame", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsInGame", false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName, bool state)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        if (state)
        {
            if (TotalSelected > 5 + MainWindow.HomeSubCount)
            {
                this.IsInGame = false;
                return;
            }

            if (MainWindow.HomeTeam.Count < 5)
                MainWindow.HomeTeam.Add(this);
            else
            {
                if (MainWindow.HomeSub.Count < MainWindow.HomeSubCount)
                {
                    MainWindow.HomeSub.Add(this);
                }
            }
            TotalSelected++;
        }
        else
        {

            if (SearchForMe(MainWindow.HomeTeam) != null)
            {
                MainWindow.HomeTeam.Remove(SearchForMe(MainWindow.HomeTeam));
                TotalSelected--;
                return;
            }

            if (SearchForMe(MainWindow.HomeSub) != null)
            {
                MainWindow.HomeSub.Remove(SearchForMe(MainWindow.HomeSub));
                TotalSelected--;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private Team SearchForMe(ObservableCollection<Team> OCT)
    {
        return OCT.Where(i => i.Number == this.Number).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste in the Player class a property

```
ObservableCollection<Player> CurrnetIn { get; set; }
```

and set this property, if you Add the player in some collection. Or have I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Is this passed by reference?

Comment: Yes, ObservableCollection<> is a reference type. So you can always have a reference on the container/collection the player into.

Comment: How can I access the original name of the list from CurrentIn or know whether it's Home or Away? In order to add to the new  Home or Away Observable list?

Comment: You can compare the references if (CurrnetIn == Home)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `Contains` method of the `ObservableCollection<T>` class to determine whether a specific object is already in the collection:

```
if (MainWindow.HomeTeam.Contains(this))
{
    MainWindow.HomeTeam.Remove(this);
    TotalSelected--;
    return;
}
```

Since your `Player` class doesn't implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface the references that you pass to the `Contains` method will be compared to the items in the collection which is totally fine in this case:

[Does List<String>.Contains(mystring) do a reference comparison or a value comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264223/does-liststring-containsmystring-do-a-reference-comparison-or-a-value-compar)